# Excel - Merging date and time cells

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel spreadsheet with two cells in each row that I'd like to merge. Cell A contains Date and Cell B contains Time, so I'd like to Merge both cells all the while retaining both values.

Example:

02/11/2020 09:29

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask - what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Richie,

I'm fairly new with Excel, i've tried =Concatenate and i've already tried the following formula =A2&" "&B2

Unfortunately neither of them work and i just get a combined data of decimal points and random numbers ranging up to 10 - 11 digits

Answer (score 0):

if Date is in A2 and Time is in B2, a formula of

```
=A2+B2
```

will join date and time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using the combination for calculations, use:

```
=A1+B1
```

Just format the column to show date and time.

If you want the date and time as text that will stay the same regardless of formatting, use:

```
=TEXT(A1,"DD/MM/YYYY")&" "&TEXT(B1,"HH:mm")
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose in Excel 2013 we have fields A1 = 02/11/2020 and B1 = 09:29 and we want concatenate them to single string.

`=A1+B1` will not work returning Value Error as date in such form is not additive, but time is additive in form HH:mm. This would work if date is in additive form 2020-11-02 returning explicit real value representation of date_time. This need to be proceed with date formatting of field CTRL+1 to return the accepted date string.
`=A1&B1` or `=A1&" "&B1` will join the fields in textual form but time will be expanded to real number representation
`=A1&" "&TEKST(B1;"G:MM AM/PM")`  will join the fields in textual form and wanted format

As alternative You can select A1 and B1 (or whole columns A B) and copy content to Notepad, replace Tab charter if needed, then return to excel and paste as text.